# How can I reset JavaFX mediaplayer when it ends?

Tags: javafx, media-player

I am trying to make my JavaFX media players reset when it finishes? I can't set autorepeat because I want them to randomly switch when one ends.

Comment: "Reset" in what way? You can do something like `player.setOnEndOfMedia(player::stop)` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to make it restart from the beginning and call a function that allows the program to start one of the media players. I have already written said function, the problem is just restarting it. Will player::stop reset it to the beginning?

Comment: The `player::stop` is a method reference implementing the `Runnable` interface. It simply calls [`MediaPlayer#stop()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()) and you can read the Javadoc to see what that method does. The class Javadoc also says, "_If the stop time of the cycle is reached and the cycle is to be played again, the event handler registered with the onRepeat property is invoked. If the stop time is reached and the cycle is not to be repeated, then the event handler registered with the onEndOfMedia property is invoked_", which [cont.]

Comment: tells you what the `onEndOfMedia` property does and when the `Runnable` will be invoked. By the way, you can make the `Runnable` more complicated in order to call your method when the media ends in addition to any other behavior you want to happen.